# Set size of span to static so it doesn't depend on size of content

Tags: html, css

I have two textboxes (part of a form), in the same line, and under each of them I want to place a `<span>` to show any errors with the data filled. The problem I'm facing is that the size of the error under the first box changes the position of the error under the second box.

I've added some images for clearer understanding.

[image: Standard error size]

[image: longer error]

Here is my html code:

```
            <form id="notify" method="post" action="add_notify.php">            
            Name: <input type="text" class="formname" name="name" value="" size="20"/>
            Email: <input type="text" class="formname" name="from" value="" size="20"/>
            <input type="submit" class="sendform" name="submit" onclick="processInfo()" value="Go!"/>
            <br/>
            <span id="name_error" class="nameerror">Name Error foo bar blah blah</span>
            <span id="email_error" class="emailerror">Email Error</span>
            </form>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.formname{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #30435D;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    width: 170px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.nameerror, .emailerror
{
    color:red;
    font-size:small;
    padding-left:60px;
    width:300px;


}
.emailerror
{
    padding-left:200px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use floating `<div>` to show the errors. Block level element is needed so that the `width` will affect it.

HTML:

```
<div id="name_error" class="nameerror">Name Error  foo bar blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>
<div id="email_error" class="emailerror">Email Error</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.nameerror, .emailerror
{
    float: left;
    color: red;
    font-size: small;
    width: 170px;
}

.nameerror
{
    margin-left: 45px;
}
.emailerror
{
    margin-left: 90px;
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/yW5e5/).

The extra `<div>` with "clear" is required to show further contents properly, also changed the width to the same width as the input boxes, no point having the errors longer than the inputs they represent.

Comment: Thanks! I had managed to implement it using tables by the time you posted this solution, but I scrapped the tables and got it working using divs.

Comment: btw, your solution fails if there is no name error at all. As long as there is some text for name error (even just a period), it works. I'm working around it by having `&nbsp` as a default error.

Comment: Cheers, interesting bug/feature of CSS with empty container - using `&nbsp;` will solve it indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your form into a table -- that way, the position of the contents in one column (the "name" side of the form) won't directly affect the position of the contents in the other column as you're seeing here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a table instead, replacing span(s) with columns.
If you don't want to use a table, you can always use two div(s) with the `float=left` trick.

Anyway I'll add also a simple: `text-align: left;` to nameerror and emailerror and I'll also remove the `padding-left` to emailerror.

Answer (score 0):

Shadow Wizard beat me to the punch.  Use floating divs. By setting display to block, the floating, widths work 
Here's the [solution in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5J98y/)

First See the result, then uncomment the javascript and run again to see the difference with more text added.

Since you're putting them in floating div's I'd suggest doing the same with the formatting above.  It'll depend on the logic of your layout, but my guess is that for this situation, you essentially want to columns per se, or two blocks.  Thus the left side in a 
div `{float:left; width: 200px; }` and the next div with same style, float left and all.  So make that a class and set both div's to that class.

Then clear the div's when finished with `clear: both`.  If you don't clear floats, bad things happen.

Look into the css display property, as floating, inline, etc is something that takes a bit to get your head around, but it's important to learn thoroughly off the bad.

Best of luck!

Comment: This is my final loose interpretation of how I'd play it out, with the two block divs, [js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cvdD/)posted on jsFiddle